# exception when get a subset of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to get the first, 2nd and 4th column of a data frame, which is column `c_a,c_b,c_d`, what is wrong with my code?

I post my code, data (123.csv) and error message,

```
sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
    dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:float})
sample.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_c', 'c_d'])
sample['c_d'] = sample['c_d'].astype('int64')
print sample.shape # output (3, 4)
X = sample.iloc[0, 1, 3]

    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Content of 123.csv,

```
c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d
hello,python,pandas,0.0
hi,java,pandas,1.0
ho,c++,numpy,0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 3]]` instead (or `df[[0, 1, 3]]`).

Comma separates the row indexer and the column indexer.

Comment: Nice, will mark it as answer in 9 mins per time limits. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
X = sample[['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_d']]
```

More explicit than using `iloc`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, bananafish, vote up for the reply.